# When I do and don't need attributes in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to make sure I understand all this. It seems to work but I worry when all these settings occur via the code reading my code and I'm left hoping the magic works (if it matters, I am using SQL Server as the underlying repository).

First, when I have a class as follows:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; }
}
```

It will make the column Id a primary key, auto-populate it when inserting a record, and set it to auto-increment to the next value on the next insert.

Second, when I have a PK:FK as follows:

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<County> Counties { get; set; } = new List<County>();
}

public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}
```

It will automatically set up the PK:FK relationship there. And when it reads in the State object, it will read in all the associated County objects and populate the Counties list.

Third, when I have many users and they travel in various counties, so each user has multiple counties and each county has multiple users, I set it up like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public IList<County> Counties { get; set; } = new List<County>();
}

public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And again it will connect this all up, and populate the Counties  property when loading a User object.

Fourth, what would happen if I declared the classes as follows as this would cause major recursion:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public IList<County> Counties { get; set; } = new List<County>();
}

public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<User> Users{ get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

Fifth, if it's going by property names, it understands Users vs Counties (i.e. 's' vs. 'ies'). Is there anything to watch out for on that naming handling?

Comment: There's no magic. EF is convention-based. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?source=recommendations&tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you for the link. Is there a link showing how to accomplish this with attributes? Or is that approach not as good as defining it in OnModelCreating()?

Comment: @GertArnold And... using attributes or OnModelCreating() how do I construct a many to many relationship? Because in the DB that requires a join table. TIA

Comment: If you follow the naming conventions you won't need any configuration, otherwise fluent mapping should be used. Attributes can't be used for junction table configuration.

Answer (score 0):

EF Convention will use specific rules to work out relationships. If you are using Code-first, you will see EF in action creating foreign key columns in the table which it is using shadow properties behind the scenes within the entities.

Where attributes or other specific configuration comes in are cases where you have an existing schema that doesn't conform to these rules, or otherwise want to alter the behaviour, or cases where EF cannot work out the relationship.

When mapped to existing schemas, from memory EF will look for the following PKs: Id, TableNameId, and TableName_Id. When it comes to FKs, it looks for TableNameId or TableName_Id

So in your second example:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public IList<County> Counties { get; set; } = new List<County>();
}
public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

EF will be looking for a UserId or User_Id on the County table. If running Code First it will create User_Id by default.

Where annotations really come into play is when using multiple references to the same table. For example if you have a CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy User reference on a County:

```
public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

This is where things get a wee bit different. You might expect that EF would expect/create something like CreatedBy_Id and LastModifiedBy_Id, but it actually will create User_Id and User_Id1. EF's convention is based on the ***type name*** not the property name.

```
[ForeignKey("CreatedBy_Id")]
public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("LastModifiedBy_Id")]
public User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

This would also require some work if you wanted to have a Counties collection on the User for any reason. You would need to tell EF which (if either) User collection on the County a User.Counties would refer to. Otherwise you would want something like

```
ICollection<County> CountiesICreated { get; set; }
ICollection<County> CountiesILastModified { get; set; }
```

and explicitly map these to the corresponding relationship on the other end.

Personally I don't like relying on EF's conventions for relationships given I pretty much exclusively use schema first working either with existing databases or stakeholder DBA's that are responsible for the overall schema for an organization. If in doubt, be explicit, especially for relationships.

Comment: You are discussing the third case I think. In that case it's a many to many relationship as each user can travel to several counties and each county has numerous users travelling in it. So I don't think this is a case of a foreign key added to either, but instead a join table. Am I not understanding something there?  
  
Also, I updated the second question as I forgot to include the FK there.

Comment: 3rd is same as 2nd, just /w a shadow relationship. The many-to-many scenario (4th) EF code-first will attempt to create a joining table for UserCounties (or CountyUsers). If you are using Schema-first but you may likely need to configure the relationship to use the right one.. EF can manage the relationship as a shadow entity, but if you want to record anything other than the FKs/PK(a  composite of the 2 FKs) then you would need to configure that joining entity and use it in the collections. For instance if you want a soft-delete, /w IsActive or track which user created the association, etc.